# Firebase Firestore - Access document within another document of unknown id

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i don't know how to go about accessing several documents inside a document of unknown name. Here is my Firebase Firestore structure:

- BUSINESS

  - unknownbusinessid1

    - PROMOTIONS

      - unknownpromotionid1
      - unknownpromotionid2
        (...)
  - unknownbusinessid2
    (...)
  - unknownbusinessid3
    (...)

what I would like to achieve is to retrieve all promotion documents (unknownpromotionid1, unknownpromotionid2, etc.) without knowing the business ids (unknownbusinessid1, unknownbusinessid2, unknownbusinessid3, etc.)

it should be something like this:

```
const getItem = db.doc(`BUSINESS/$whatever`).collection("PROMOTIONS")
    .get().then((snapshot) => {

        snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
            console.log("this is your promotion", doc)
        })

    return promotionsArray
})
```

how can this be accomplished?
thank you!

Comment: You can't do this with a single query.  You will have to query each subcollection individually to get all the documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *collection group query*, as detailed in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), it allows accessing subcollections with a specific name from every documents at once:

```
db.collectionGroup('PROMOTIONS').get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log("this is your promotion", doc)
   }
});
```

Note that you will need to set an index as well a an appropriate security rule for Firestore:

```
match /{path=**}/PROMOTIONS/{id} {
  allow read: if true;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Where do I add the security rule? (sorry if this is obvious, still learning)

Comment: would it be in firestore console like this? 

```rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
    match /{path=**}/PROMOTIONS/{id} {
   allow read: if true;
}
  }
}```

Comment: Great, you have found it! You can write your rules either in the firestore.rules file or directly in the Firebase console.

Comment: Your rule looks good to me, you can check with the rule playground in the console.